# localtime returns null

Tags: c

localtime returns null. Why? (I'm using Visual C++ 2008)

```
struct tm    *tb;   
time_t       lDate;      

time(&lDate);

tb = localtime(&lDate); // tb is null everytime I try this!
```

Comment: Hello, can you provide the entire code please ? It works with gcc on my computer and I want to test your code.

Comment: Can you check `errno` after the call to `localtime` and tell us what the value is?

Comment: @Luke `localtime` does not set `errno`, check the man page.

Comment: @Jonathan I have no idea about the linux version, but the Microsoft version certainly does, and he's using VC++ 2008. Though it looks like it may only ever set it to EINVAL, which is pretty useless here.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf12f0hc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Is that your exact code? I just compiled this program and it works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct tm *tb;
    time_t lDate;

    time(&lDate);
    if (lDate == -1) {
        perror("time");
        return 1;
    }

    tb = localtime(&lDate);
    if (tb == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "localtime failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Good\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 #include <time.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(void)
  {
     // get the current time
     time_t now = time(0);
     struct tm* theTime = localtime(&now);
     int t=(int)theTime;
     printf("%d",t);
     getch();
     return 0;
  }
```

it works

Answer (score 1):

Define the preprocessor **_USE_32BIT_TIME_T** in your project and try again. Good luck:)

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted in your comments works fine, up until you get to the if statement.  I'm not sure what you are trying to do here, but you have a `;` in `if (pArea);` that almost definitely should not be there (hard to tell since it's formatted horribly because you put it in a comment).  You are also returning 0 all the time, is that what you intended to do?